# Angular 2 get request in series

Tags: json, angular, http, callback, angular2-services

I have a configuration service which is used to retrieve specific information from a json file.

```
 getConfiguration(key) {
    return this.http.get('./app/config/development.json').map(res => {
      this.result = res.json();
      return this.result[key];
    });
  }
```

I'm trying to get my base url of my api (in development.json), and use this url to make requests.

```
getJoueurs() {
    this.conf.getConfiguration('apiBaseUrl').subscribe((url: any) => {
      return this.http.get(url + 'joueur').map(res => res = res.json());
    });
  }
```

So, I subscribe to get my configuration back, and then trying to return an observable object, to catch it in my component.

Here in my component:

```
this.requestService.getJoueurs().subscribe((joueurs) => console.log(joueurs));
```

The fact is that i'm having an error on subscribe "does not exist on type void". What am i doing wrong here, and what is the proper way to make get request in series.

Comment: The reason you're getting the "void" error is your `getJoueurs()` function doesn't return anything. It runs `getConfiguration()` yes but it doesn't output anything that could be subscribed to. Julia's answer below will help you solve the rest but she missed the return as well for the moment..

Comment: I don't really understand, the method "getjoueurs" is returning the observable object 
      return this.http.get(url + 'joueur').map(res => res = res.json());
This line is supposed to return my observable object.
Can you help me to figure this out Dennis ?
Effectively in julia's answer nothing is returned in the getJoueurs method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I'm going to answer to be able to explain a little bit. @julia's Answer was mostly there but it's still going to not work for your function.

My guess is your line: `this.requestService.getJoueurs().subscribe((joueurs) => console.log(joueurs));` is a stand-in for your actual use case, so I'm going to address it vs Julia's method of logging out in the function itself. (which totally works)

You can see with typescript and types what is happening with your subscription. You aren't returning anything in the `getJoueurs()` function.

```js
var myPhrase = "Do I show up?";

console.log(myPhrase);
console.log('no:', noIDont());
console.log('yes:', yesIDo());

function noIDont() {
    myPhrase = 'oh no';
}

function yesIDo() {
    myPhrase = 'Yay!';
    return myPhrase;
}

// You will see:
// Do I show up?
// No:
// Yes: Yay!
```

Your functions need to **return** a value

If we were more hardcore with the typescript on your functions you could write those examples as:

```
function noIDont(): void {
        myPhrase = 'oh no';
    }

    function yesIDo(): string {
        myPhrase = 'Yay!';
        return myPhrase;
    }
```

So to modify the whole block to include Julia's example:

```
      // Get Config
getConfiguration(key): Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get('./app/config/development.json').map(res => {
      this.result = res.json();
      return this.result[key];
    });
  }

// Get Joueurs, notice the type for the return
getJoueurs(): Observable<any> {
//▼▼▼▼▼▼ MUST HAVE   
  return this.conf.getConfiguration('apiBaseUrl')
     .switchMap((url: any) => this.http.get(url + 'joueur'))
                                .map(res => res = res.json()
     );
}



// calling script in the component:
this.requestService.getJoueurs().subscribe((joueurs) => console.log(joueurs));
```

So yeah, Julia's `switchMap` or a `flatMap` works great, just be sure to return a value in your functions.the `subscribe "does not exist on type void"` error is because you were returning `null` when you need to return a `Observable<T>`

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use switchMap/mergeMap/concatMap operator:

here is switchMap that I mostly use:

> Projects each source value to an Observable which is merged in the output Observable, emitting values only from the most recently projected Observable.
>   http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html

if you have expireence with AngularJS and want to start using Observales you can take a look at my post:
**$Q map to RxJS**  https://medium.com/@juliapassynkova/q-map-to-rxjs-981936a2b22d

```
getJoueurs() {
   this.conf.getConfiguration('apiBaseUrl')
     .switchMap((url: any) => this.http.get(url + 'joueur'))
                                .map(res => res = res.json()
     )
     .subscribe(joueurs => console.log(joueurs));
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to return the results, your code now only executes and `getJoueurs()` doesn't return anything.. That's the reason for the void..

Comment: the original result was doing .subscribe((joueurs) => console.log(joueurs));.

Comment: Thanks Julia for your answer, but i'm not getting any result by using the switchMap in this case.